# How to pre-create federated Azure AD (AAD) users in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have our main AAD federated to our Azure AD B2C using OpenID Connect. For metadata I'm using the following endpoint: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant_id%7D/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration)

This set up works fine when users are sign up. When a user signs up, a user is created in B2C. But I need to create these users in advance. For this purpose, I'm using Microsoft Graph APIs to create users. The following code creates a user in B2C but it is not correctly linked to AAD user. When I try to login with AAD user in B2C, it gives me following error

AADB2C99002: User does not exist. Please sign up before you can sign in.

```
var user = new User
            {
                AccountEnabled = true,
                DisplayName = "Last, First",
                Identities = new List<ObjectIdentity>()
                {
                    new ObjectIdentity
                    {
                        SignInType = "federated",
                        Issuer = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/v2.0",
                        IssuerAssignedId = "{**unique_user_object_id_from_federated_active_directory**}"
                    }
                },
                PasswordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration"
            };
```

Answer (score 2):

I demonstrated this scenario here in detail:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/link-local-account-with-federated-account

Comment: Thank you. We also have access to AAD (our main directory) and can read user info. So ideally we'd like to create B2C users already linked to AAD just using Microsoft Graph APIs. That way we don't have to worry about custom policy. Is this possible?

Comment: That’s exactly what the sample does.

Comment: But isn't the sample using a custom policy? I'm looking to avoid use of custom policy.

Comment: In my case what worked was passing the "oid" value from AAD claims to "IssuerAssignedId".

Comment: That’s right, the matching criteria to a B2C account is the issuer (some static string) and issuerId (AAD objectId). You can dump a user with graph api that was signed up via AAD federation and inspect the identities attribute to see how it’s formatted in full. By making your new user conform to that, it’ll work with user flow too.